# R: Select rows of a matrix where a specific column has a specific value

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements

I have a matrix *m* with 4 columns and 100 rows. The head of the matrix looks like this:

```
    head(m)
      [,1]  [,2]     [,3]       [,4]
 [1,] 1256 1.0000000 3.709184    0
 [2,] 8402 0.4226495 3.644793    0
 [3,]  656 0.4117985 3.165158    0
 [4,] 3925 0.4098163 3.239075    0
 [5,] 4987 0.4077779 3.471448    0
 [6,] 4715 0.4051867 3.400527    2
```

What I want to do is to select all the rows where the fourth column is different from 0.In the example above, I should get back :

```
     [,1]  [,2]     [,3]       [,4]
 [1,] 4715 0.4051867 3.400527    2
```

I tried the following which command:

```
    m[,which(m[,4]!=0)]
```

but I keep getting an error "*index is out of limit*. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easy way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: you've misplaced the comma - `m[which(m[,4]!=0),]`

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Also, you don't need which: `m[m[,4]!=0,]` will work too.

Comment: @John, feel free to add an answer of your own and accept it to show that this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was simply a misplaced comma as [eddi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817778/eddi) mentioned. The solution should be:

```
    m[which(m[,4]!=0),]
```

Also, as mentioned by [mrip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588184/mrip) , the use of *which* is not necessary. I could have simply used:

```
    m[m[,4]!=0,]
```